# Do you recognize these fonts?

Tags: font-identification

I am trying to identify the different fonts in this article from a Cuban newspaper published in the 1950s. [image]
I think the body of the text is Baskerville, btu what about "Estrellas" or "Por Fausto Miranda" or the bullet points underneath?
Any ideas are much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Hi gsosa9 and welcome to GD! I've helped identify the fonts in your question but for future reference, we have some [requirements and useful online resources](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/what-are-the-requirements-for-font-identification-questions/2366#2366) for font identification questions, please take a look and edit your question to include that information.

Comment: I do... I think one of them owes me money.

Comment: Hi zeethreepio, thanks for your help! As well as including the requirements. Just started here and I hadn't seen those.

Answer (score 1):

The "ESTRELLAS" text could be either [Onyx Std](https://www.fontshop.com/families/monotype-onyx) or [Arsis](https://www.fontshop.com/families/linotype-arsis):

[image]

[image]

These typefaces are based off of **Bodoni**, so I think you'd be safe to assume [Bodoni Pro Italic](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/bodoni/pro-italic/) for the bullet text:

[image]

---

***Interesting note:*** If the "Estrella" typefaces look identical, they just might be. Both Onyx Std and Arsis were designed by Gerry Powell in 1937 and 1938 respectively with one designed for Monotype (Onyx Std) and one for Linotype (Arsis). Since we know these typefaces existed in the 1950s (when your sample was published), the true answer can only be resolved by knowing which method of typesetting the publisher was using. This argument is moot in the digital age though.

Comment: It's much simpler than that. American Type Founders around 1900 created a revival of "Bodoni" that included condensed weights like this, like nothing Bodoni himself ever did. They were very popular and every printing company did their own knockoff of them, just like these days every dance music producer seems to copy what other people are doing. My guess is that Gerry Powell drew a version for Monotype and Linotype licensed it (or vice versa) on condition of a name change. Printing companies did a lot of that.

Answer (score 0):

The body text is one of Linotype's "Legibility Group" fonts, which were used all over the world in newspapers, or a copy of it. There were several fonts in this family with different names - look at "Ionic No. 5" and "Excelsior" and they should be about right.